# Need some help calling another another class's method in another class

Tags: java, variables, joptionpane

I'm a noob at Java, learning to try get my head around OOP.

I'm trying to integrate classes and pass get `secondwindow.form2('null')` to work.

I have no idea how to pass through variables to other classes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class helloworld {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                JFrame window = new JFrame("Hello world test");
                window.setVisible(true);
                window.setSize(500,500);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "do NOT click 'OK'");
                String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(window,"Enter a sentence");
                int characters =word.length();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, characters);
                NewDialouge secondwindow = new NewDialouge();
                secondwindow.form2('null');
            }   
        });         
    }

}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewDialouge {

    public void form2(String spoon){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(spoon,  "works.");

    }

}
```

Comment: Use double quotes for Strings. Why do you have 'null', when in all the other places you've used the correct format?

Comment: single quotes like this : `'a'` are for chars, double qoutes like this : `"foobar"` are for strings

Comment: Note: There's no need to add "[JAVA]" to the title -- that's information much better conveyed by the tags.

Comment: That is a lot of 'another' in your title there...

Answer (score 0):

```
secondwindow.form2('null');
```

Is wrong, in Java characters are enclosed in single quotes, for Strings you need to use double quotes.